# Publishing to Azure through VS not working?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to publish one of my aspnetcore projects through the Azure App Service.  What happens when I try to do it through Visual Studio is that it seems to get stuck loading my Microsoft account, and will not populate any of the dropdowns.

[image: VS Azure Error]

The same happens for both trying to create a new azure app service and selecting an existing one.

I did some research into the problem and saw that I should create a test app service through the azure portal to see if it would show up if I selected an existing project.  Sadly, it did not work.  Is there a reason that it will not fully load my account or fill in the dropdowns?  Or is there an alternative method to getting my project onto Azure?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your account details in VS? e.g. Remove your Microsoft account and add it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is not working for you, create your app service first in the Azure portal at https://portal.azure.com

Then download the Publish Profile.

So instead of publishing having to sign in, you 'Import Profile', locate your downloaded file and once that is done, you can publish.

This should for work you.

Another way is to have your code in a repository (https://dev.azure.com) and configure builds for it. - If you need help with this, kindly reply on this.